# How many three digits even numbers can we form such that if one of digit is $5$ the following digit must be $ 7$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many three digits even numbers can we form such that if one of digit is $5$ the following digit must be $ 7$?

I need some ideas on how to proceed on this problem.

Comment: If your three digit number is $abc$ with $c$ even, you either have $57c$ or $abc$ with $a \neq 5 \neq b$, am I right? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: If the beginning is $5$, then next is $7$, now how many ways for last? If the beginning is not $5$ ($8$ ways), the next is anything but $5$ (how many ways?) and the last is even (how many ways?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different kinds of such three-digit even numbers.

- $57x$, where $x$ can only be $0,2,4,6,8$ which is just $5$ possibilities.
- For the remaining, you count all even three-digit numbers with no $5$ in them. This will be $8\times 9\times 5 = 360$

So you have $365$ possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

required number of ways = number of ways is number of ways of forming a 3 digit even number(10.10.5)- number of even numbers  in which 5 is the first digit and 7 is not the second digit(1.9.5) = 455

Comment: 10 choices for the first digit? Really?